# Too many redirects with URL Rewrite

Tags: iis, url-rewriting, iis-6

I have the below config added for a redirect which works for this domain but for www version it doesnt redirect to the https version of the site

```
    <rule name="Site Http" patternSyntax="Wildcard" stopProcessing="true">
      <match url="*" />
      <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAny">
        <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="test.example.uk" />   
      </conditions>
      <action type="Redirect" url="https://www.example.com/{R:0}" />
    </rule>
    <rule name="Site to HTTPS" stopProcessing="true">
        <match url="(.*)" />
        <conditions trackAllCaptures="true">
            <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="test.example.uk" />
            <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="www.example.com" />
            <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="^((www\.)?example.com)$" />
            <add input="{HTTPS}" pattern="off" />
        </conditions>
        <action type="Redirect" url="https://{C:1}{REQUEST_URI}" appendQueryString="false" redirectType="Permanent"/>
    </rule>
```

So no matter which domain i have listed i want it to go to the https version of the site (https://www.example.com) but if i enter domain.com it redirects to https, if i enter test.domain.uk it goes to https but if i enter [www.example.com](http://www.example.com) it remains on http?

If i add

```
<add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="www.example.com" />
```

to the Site Http rule i get too many redirects error in a browser.

How could i redirect [www.example.com](http://www.example.com) to https?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/extensions/url-rewrite-module/using-failed-request-tracing-to-trace-rewrite-rules

Comment: Hi, has the problem been solved? If you think my reply is helpful to you, you can mark it as an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try to use this URL Rewrite rule:

```
<rewrite>
  <rules>
    <rule name="Test" stopProcessing="true">
        <match url="^(.*)$" ignoreCase="false" />
        <conditions>
            <add input="{HTTP_X_FORWARDED_PROTO}" pattern="^http$" ignoreCase="false" />
         </conditions>
      <action type="Redirect" url="https://{SERVER_NAME}{URL}" redirectType="Found" />
    </rule>
  </rules>
</rewrite>
```

**The meaning of the following rule is that if the HTTP header X-Forwarded-Proto contains "https", the rule will not perform redirection.**

```
<add input="{HTTP_X_FORWARDED_PROTO}" pattern="^http$" ignoreCase="false" />
```

This rule will avoid circular redirects.

Comment: Do I need to replace both rules from my example provided with the one you have supplied?  Also what is the purpose of url="https://{SERVER_NAME}{URL - an I still on to use what I have in my original example?

Comment: You can use it, or you can directly add <add input="{HTTP_X_FORWARDED_PROTO}" pattern="^http$" ignoreCase="false" /> to your URL Rewrite rule.

Comment: SERVER_NAME: The server's host name, DNS alias, or IP address as it would appear in self-referencing URLs. URL: The base portion of the URL without any querystring information.